# Accessing cropped image when using CropViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a very simple application - there is an image, a button and an empty image view.

When you press the button you are taken to the crop view where you can edit the image to be a circle. I have installed CropViewController through cocoa pods.

However, when I press 'Done' the cropped image is not shown in the empty image view - the method for that is never called.

Any advice would be fantastic!

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CropViewController

class ViewController: UIViewController, CropViewControllerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func cropImage(_ sender: Any)
    {
        presentCropViewController()

    }

    func presentCropViewController()
    {
        let image: UIImage? = imageView.image
        let cropViewController = CropViewController(croppingStyle: .circular, image: image!)
        cropViewController.delegate = self
        self.present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didCropToCircularImage image: UIImage?, with cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int)
    {
    // 'image' is the newly cropped, circular version of the original image
        self.resultImage.image = image
    }

    func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didFinishCancelled cancelled: Bool) {
        cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed out the @objc tags

```
@objc func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didCropToCircularImage image: UIImage?, with cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int)
    {
    // 'image' is the newly cropped, circular version of the original image
        self.resultImage.image = image
    }

@objc func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didFinishCancelled cancelled: Bool) {
        cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        })
    }
```

Comment: If you have solved your issue with the above solution, mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i use the

```
func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
        // 'image' is the newly cropped version of the original image
        self.yourImageView.image = image
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

instead of the didCropToCircular thing. Works for me